# Determining calendar availability, search algorithm and db structure

Tags: database, algorithm

need to design an availability application.

The users would mark on a calendar all their events, just like a regular calendar. Then I would need to search for something like, "I need someone from next Thursday afternoon through Saturday morning". So what I'm searching for is the negative of what the user puts in - the user puts in time slots when they're NOT available, and I search for the slots when they are.

The simplest thing I can think of is to just put down the calendar info in these 2 tables,

User (id, name, etc.... )
Events (id, user_id_foreign_key, time_start, time_end, type)

The "type" in Event is probably going to be used for something like "daily", "weekly", etc. for infinitely repeating events. Haven't really figured out how to handle those yet...

So all I really have to do is to search for whether or not, for each user, if any of their events' start / end times fall within the time range I gave (i.e., events' start times are earlier than the range's end time OR events' end times are later than the range's start time). If they do then the user is unavailable. I'd of course have to cycle through all the users to do this.

Does this sound like the most efficient way to do this? Came up with this myself so would like to get some feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't sound like the most efficient way to do this if the number of users and events grows large in your system.

For example, if you would store the FREE time intervals in your database instead, you would be able to find all the available users with a single database query (find all free intervals that contain the interval you search for, and join this with the users data table). The free intervals data table should be indexed with both start and end times of the intervals.

Maintaining free intervals is a bit more complicated, because when you add an event you normally would split a free interval. But for the search if would be a better datastructure.